# How to mock navigator.geolocation in a LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, mock, lwc-jest

Having a component that uses the embedded `geolocation` feature to get coordinates, how can I mock the call in a Jest test?

The component's code work in the org:

```
...

get locationService () {
    return navigator.geolocation
}

...

getCurrentPosition () {
    if (this.locationService) {
        let component = this
        this.locationService.getCurrentPosition(position => {
            component.markers = [{
                location: {
                    Latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                    Longitude: position.coords.longitude
                },
                title: 'You are here!'
            }]
            component.coordinates.lat = position.coords.latitude
            component.coordinates.lon = position.coords.longitude
        })
    }
}

...
```

But how can I test it, since having the following mock implementation results in an error when calling `afterEach`?

```
it('Should display the coordinate.', () => {

    const mockGeolocation = {
        getCurrentPosition: jest.fn()
            .mockImplementation((success) => Promise.resolve(success({
                coords: {
                    latitude: 10,
                    longitude: 10
                }
            })))
    }

    navigator.geolocation = mockGeolocation

    ...


    ... rest of the test goes below
})
```

The error on `afterEach` is this one on the terminal:

```
Assert Violation: undefined is not a vm.

      36 |     afterEach(() => {
      37 |         while (document.body.firstChild) {
    > 38 |             document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild)
         |             ^
      39 |         }
      40 |         jest.clearAllMocks()
      41 |     })
```

The error doesn't show up if I comment out the line that assigns the `mockGeolocation` object to the `navigator.geolocation`:

```
// navigator.geolocation = mockGeolocation
```

Comment: I copied over the goelocation mock and a simplified version of your `getCurrentPosition` method and I'm unable to reproduce the error. Have you tried running your test with a debugger attached to see if there's any other errors being thrown that could give some clues?

Comment: I can't, but can you share your code?

Comment: Sure, I added the code to a fork of lwc-recipes. You can checkout the branch below and after installing run `npm run test:unit -- force-app/main/default/lwc/hello/`

https://github.com/trevor-bliss/lwc-recipes/commit/f567693d86599c80c619958f70522f18770b6c6e

Comment: Let's move the conversation to GitHub then. I posted a comment with a piece of code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Most info copied from discussion on the sample git commit [here](https://github.com/trevor-bliss/lwc-recipes/commit/f567693d86599c80c619958f70522f18770b6c6e).*

The technique you used to mock out the `navigator.geolocation` API is fine. The relevant code block from the original question is the following:

```
const mockGeolocation = {
    getCurrentPosition: jest.fn().mockImplementation((success) => 
        Promise.resolve(
            success({
                coords: {
                    latitude: 10,
                    longitude: 10
                }
            })
        )
    )
}

navigator.geolocation = mockGeolocation
```

The error referenced in the question is because a property was attempted to be accessed which did not have the `@api` decorator attached to it, making it a private property and inaccessible from the test case.

Comment: But this is only a mock for success function. How do you mock the error function? I tried somethind like this: `getCurrentPosition: jest.fn()
                    .mockImplementationOnce(error => Promise.reject(error(new Error('whaaaat')))),` But my error fucntion code gets never reached.